# How can I automatically extract content from a field in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The environment I am currently working in is Snowflake.
As a matter of data sensitivty, I will be using pseudonyms for my following question.

I have a specific field in one of my tables called FIELD_1. The data in this field is structured as such:

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to **automatically** extract from my FIELD_1 the output I have in FIELD_2.

Does anyone have any idea what kind of query I would need to achieve this? Any help would be GREATLYappreciated! I am really quite stuck on this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck in that attempt? Can you share your code that doesn't meet your requirements as a [mre], along with where *specifically* the attempt is falling short? [ask]

Comment: Hi, I honestly don't even know where to start in terms of my query. I am not sure what function to use in my query. I have never tried this type of automatic extraction before and I can't seem to find any useful information in any Snowflake documentation.

Comment: For future reference, Stack Overflow isn't a great place if you truly "*don't know where to start*". Fundamentals of a particular language or toolset are best left to things like tutorials, discussion forums, and vendor documentation. Questions here are generally expected to demonstrate some good-faith effort in researching and implementation prior to posting here in accordance with our [ask] guidelines.

Comment: Ok thank you for the future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want everything up to the first four numbers.  Then to replace the underscores with spaces.  If so:

```
select replace(regexp_substr(field_1, '^[^0-9]*[0-9]{4}'), '_', ' ')
```

Or alternatively, if you want the first three components separated by underscores:

```
select replace(regexp_substr(field_1, '^[^_]+_[^_]+_[0-9]{4}'), '_', ' ')
```

Comment: This is not working correctly, it returns Blue_Car_20210923 for the first example because regexp is greedy. Do you know how to make it not greedy in Snowflake?

Comment: @MajaF. . . . Your initial characters don't seem to be digits, so you can look for non-digits until the first four.

Comment: Hi Gordon, this is exactly the solution that I need, thank you so much! If possible, do you tihnk you could breakdown what exactly this code means: '^[^0-9]*[0-9]{4}' . I have found some documentation on this topic but it is not clear online. thank you so much once again!

Comment: It means "select all initial characters that are not digits followed by four digits".

Comment: thanks a bunch Gordon, you have been a tremendous help!

Answer (score 0):

If the data is as simplistic in reality as you've described here, you can use a variable-length `LEFT()` function in conjunction with `REPLACE()` to get the desired output:

```
SELECT FIELD_1, REPLACE(LEFT(FIELD_1, LEN(FIELD_1)-10),'_',' ') AS FIELD_2
FROM table_name
```

See also:

- [`SELECT` - Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/select.html)
- [`LEFT` - Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/left.html)
- [`REPLACE` - Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace.html)
- [`LENGTH`, `LEN` - Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/length.html)

Comment: This has worked great! My data is not in essence as simplistic as I've included in the example above. I have however included in in the way FIELD_1 is built (from my BI team) a unique character to aid with this automatic extraction. Essentially, all charatcers I want to extract into my FIELD_2  are separated by an "_" and everything I want to discard is separated by a unique charatcer, a dash "-". Do you know how I could include in the query above this factor? That I want to discard everything after the dash.